# Counting the values of an array with nesting

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array, which is a load of arrays nested in a bigger array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [vote_for] => 2
        )

)
```

I want to do the equivalent of array_count_values on this array, such that I get `15 => 3`, `5 => 2` and `2 => 10`. How do I un-nest the arrays to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try reforming your array to count:

```
$count_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
   $count_array[] = $v['vote_for'];
}

// Now get the counts
$the_count = array_count_values($count_array);
```

Comment: Thanks PhpMyCoder. I started with a different method and then changed mid-way, forgetting to update the `foreach()` to a different level. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think array map will also work for this

```
$count_array = array_map(function($item) { return $item['vote_for']; }, $array);
$the_count = array_count_values($count_array);
```